# Jquery fadeIn and fadeOut background Command

Tags: jquery, transition, fadein, fadeout

I have a scrolling background image using Jquery that is working fine. However I am trying to make the transitions between the image changes smoother and it doesn't seem to work. I'm sure it has something to do with the "fadeOut" line I used.

```
$(function() {
var body = $('body');
var backgrounds = new Array(
    'url(images/hso-boardwalk-background.jpg)',
    'url(images/hso-palmtree-background.jpg)' 
);

var current = 0;

function nextBackground() {
body.css(
   'background',
    backgrounds[current = ++current % backgrounds.length]
);

 setTimeout(nextBackground, 5000);
    $('background').fadeOut("slow");
 }
 setTimeout(nextBackground, 5000);
   body.css('background', backgrounds[0]);
});
```

Comment: `$('background')` What is `background` tag? Could you provide a jsfiddle?

Comment: background is no specific "id" or "div". Isn't background recognized as the actual background?

Comment: No, it isn't! Here you are targeting a tag of type `background`. But what is the result you are expecting here? Fade out only the body background?

Comment: Yes exactly. I have two background images that change every 5 seconds. All that works fine I would just like the transition to be a lot slower when they change.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot do smooth transition using only body background image. As a workaround, you could try to use a temp DIV as following:

[SEE DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/2tsY8/show/)

```
$(function () {
    var body = $('body');
    var backgrounds = new Array(
       'url(images/hso-boardwalk-background.jpg)',
       'url(images/hso-palmtree-background.jpg)' 
    );


    var current = 0;

    function nextBackground() {
        var bckg = backgrounds[current = ++current % backgrounds.length];
        var tmpDIV = $('<div/>', {
            id: "tmpDIV"
        }).prependTo('body').hide().css({
            position: "absolute",
            zIndex:-1,
            top:0,
            left:0,
            height: $(window).height(),
            width: $(window).width(),
            background: bckg
        }).fadeIn("slow", function () {
            body.css('background',bckg);
            $(this).remove();
        });


        setTimeout(nextBackground, 5000);

    }
    setTimeout(nextBackground, 5000);
    body.css('background', backgrounds[0]);
});
```

Comment: Ahh yes it works. Thank you so much for your time :) There was no way I would have thought to do that, I'm sort of a beginner in Jquery...